# How do I add error data to a response that's not technically an exception?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my app I'm throwing a custom exception. My middleware will catch that exception and send back a response with the correct status code and a helpful error response

```
 public HttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {

       try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex.StatusCode;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = ex.ContentType;

            // write to response body
            var errorObj = new { ErrorCode = ex.ErrorCode, Message = ex.Message };
            var serializedJsonError = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorObj);
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(serializedJsonError);
        }
    }
```

This works great and I can see the response in the network request along with the status code. The issue is that my front end app (angular) doesn't see any of the details in the catch block because I guess it's not technically an exception.

I know I can do something like ex.Data.Add("Mykey", "myValue") to an exception but there's not really an exception object being returned; WHen I inspect the exception I can see all of the values are empty and it probably just shows up as an error because of the status code.

What can I do to include this information so that my front end app can view the details?

This is what I'm getting back currently:

```
{  
   "data":null,
   "status":-1,
   "config":{  
      "method":"DELETE",
      "transformRequest":[  
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[  
         null
      ],
      "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
      "headers":{  
         "Authorization":"Bearer REDACTED",
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      "url":"https://7ec106dd.ngrok.io/api/Cenpos/RecurringTokens/s"
   },
   "statusText":"",
   "xhrStatus":"error"
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to send to your app? Do you have a JSON representation? I am trying to understand your problem

Comment: You could always rethrow the exception if you want to handle it outside of this function.

Comment: I updated my answer to include what I"m getting back inside my app. As you can see data is null, status is -1, method is right at least.

An error on any other call has this information which leads me to believe I'm missing something.

Comment: Figured it out!! httpContext.Response.Clear(); was the offending piece of code. Gah

Answer (score 0):

You’re using Clear(), which will prevent those other values from being set.

(Sorry for the brief answer; I’m on mobile)

Comment: Annnd I just saw your earlier comment saying that it was the problem, hahaha. Oh well.